# 3-way merge tool for C#/SQL/Javascript development on Windows - BeyondCompare or Kdiff3 or?

Tags: windows, programming, diff, merge

I'm looking for recommendations on three-way merge tools for .net development on windows. As a software developer working mostly with C#, SQL, Javascript, AngularJS I've typically used kdiff3 but heard good things about Beyond Compare. I'm happy to pay some money for a good tool so Beyond Compare's $60 is fine. But I'd like to know how they differ or if there's a better option. I've trialled Beyond Compare but basically not put the effort into researching what I get that I don't get with kdiff.

In the past I've found kdiff good but not very intuitive when doing more complex merges, and just not as pretty as Beyond Compare. But for example I don't know how the cleverness of their compare algorithms are or how some of their more advanced features compare. What do you get for paying some money?

Mostly I'll be using it for three-way merge on individual local files with TortoiseHg or SourceTree. i.e. not remote/SFTP/etc and not comparing folders.

Comment: Good question but you may have to remove the software comparison part as software comparisons are off-topic at this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), an open source differencing and merging tool for Windows. Its recent version supports 3-way File Comparison.

[image: WinMerge for Windows - feature - 3-way File Comparison]

Comment: Is it any good/better/worse than kdiff or BeyondCompare? I really liked the 2-way WinMerge in the past but 3-way is a lot harder.

Comment: Didn't use _BeyondCompare_, but I've been using _Meld_, and was disappointed that there is no version for Linux/macOS. Currently, I use `vimdiff`, so I can use it across different environments.

Comment: Imagine you implement a feature and nobody notices it... I didn't even think that Winmerge could be back under active development since it has been forgotten for 5 years

Answer (score 0):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), a free visual diff and merge tool, can do two- and three-way comparison of files and directories.

[image: Meld for Windows, Merge mode, automatically merge two files using a common ancestor]